# PHP write and save database credentials - Best practise

Tags: php, database, installation

I would like to write a setup script for my PHP application, which dose a minimum requirements check, gets the DB credentials, DB prefix and saves them, creates the db tables and so on. Now I would like to know what is the best practise to write and save the DB credentials? Write them as an array into a .php file and? Or into an XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a best practise for this, there are so many ways people use configuration files. Some use PHP arrays, some use XML files, some use INI files, some use JSON files and I'm sure some people create proprietary formats.

What you do want to take in account is, where will you store this file. If it is in the document root, people could request it. XML/INI/JSON files are plain-text and by default, will make it easy for people to 'retrieve' the file contents. PHP will be parsed server side so just returns an empty page.

Ideally you'd store the configuration file outside of the document root, but not all webhosts allow you to do so. So I'd say, if you want to release an application people can install themselves easily, a PHP file might be the easiest way to go.

Comment: What's the best practise regarding writing/reading the php file? Just simple file writing with fopen etc? Seems a bit insecure. Couldn't find a good tutorial on how to write PHP config files.

Comment: Both `fopen` and `file_put_contents` are the most commonly used functions for this. If you are afraid about the 'security' just could always add some checks before writing, to make sure the user input doesn't have anything bad in it.

Answer (score 1):

Write them as an array into a .php file. This satisfies speed (no xml parser and file touching is needed per-page), and security (.php files don't get served as text like your xml would).

I also tend to put the private.php that contains my mysql credentials in the directory above the http root, and load it like require_once("../private.php");

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about setting up the environment, correct? If that is the case, then it depends on the script or build system itself. We are using [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) where such configuration is stored in `build.properties`. For example:

```
# database credentials
db.host=localhost
db.user=root
db.pass=root
db.name=db_name
```

This file is working copy specific and as such is not a part of our VC, however, `build.properties.dist` is. This way A's local settings don't override B's.

If the question is about something else, please, do tell :)